# Remove AWS API Gateway response headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway rest API with HTTP_PROXY integration and a usage plan for throttling.  The responses from the API include several headers AWS adds, including:

- `x-amz-apigw-id`: F5TU4GpToAUFmwA=
- `x-amz-cf-id`: iGT7lD_zQsFoFg1ulYZY1pnxRPkdJMwEdjxzdGHaOhdZtYFlPFxcyQ==
- `x-amz-cf-pop`: HIO50-C2
- `x-amzn-remapped-connection`: Keep-Alive
- `x-amzn-remapped-date`: Thu, 15 Mar 2023 22:32:12 GMT
- `x-amzn-remapped-server`: Apache
- `x-amzn-requestid`: 36713d13-8s32-4f5e-865e-b32bd24f7a0c
- `x-cache`: Miss from cloudfront
- `x-ratelimit-limit`: 50
- `x-ratelimit-remaining`: 47

I'd like to remove these response headers so they don't go to the requestor. How can this be done?  It seems like [some cannot be removed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html#edge-function-restrictions-all), such as `X-Amz-Cf-*` (since API Gateway uses CloudFront behind the scenes).  And a [proxy integration can't use a mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html).  So I am wondering if it is possible to remove any of these, and if so, how it is done.